# LINQ Large data manipulation. Out of memory exception

Tags: c#, .net, linq, out-of-memory, data-manipulation

```
 IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>> data = Enumerable.Repeat(new List<object> {10, "Twenty", 30, 40, DateTime.UtcNow }, int.MaxValue);
```

Lets assume this is my data, it represents rows and columns, and the size of the data is Int.MaxValue (yes very very big).

So as an example this is how it would look:

```
10, "Twenty", 30, 40, 21/08/2016 00:00:00
10, "Twenty", 30, 40, 21/08/2016 00:00:00
10, "Twenty", 30, 40, 21/08/2016 00:00:00
10, "Twenty", 30, 40, 21/08/2016 00:00:00
10, "Twenty", 30, 40, 21/08/2016 00:00:00
..repeated int.maxvalue times.
```

Ok as we can see there are 5 columns and int.maxvalue rows.

What I want to do is apply a logic to each column. So let's say:

Column 1 Logic = "NoRepeat" (Means there should only be 1 value in this column)

Column 2 Logic = "Unique" (Means there should only be unique values in this column)

Column 3 Logic = "Disabled" (Means there should be NO VALUES in this column)

Column 4 and 5 logic = "Default" (Means leave it as it is).

SO in the end this should be the expected result:

```
10, "Twenty", "", 40, 21/08/2016 00:00:00
"", "",       "", 40, 21/08/2016 00:00:00
"", "",       "", 40, 21/08/2016 00:00:00
"", "",       "", 40, 21/08/2016 00:00:00
"", "",       "", 40, 21/08/2016 00:00:00
```

I managed to do this using LINQ but 10 million rows is as much as I could manipulate before it throws out of memory exception.

Can someone help me out with this please?

This is current implementation that I have:

```
var group = data.SelectMany(x => x.Select((InnerValue, Index) => new { Index, InnerValue })).GroupBy(x => x.Index).Select(x =>
            {
                string logicType = logics.ElementAt(x.First().Index);

                switch (logicType)
                {
                    case "NoRepeat":
                        return x.Select((OuterValue, Index) => new { Index, OuterValue }).Select(y =>
                            {
                                return y.Index == 0 ? y.OuterValue.InnerValue : string.Empty;
                            });
                    case "Unique":
                        return x;
                    case "Disabled":
                        return x;
                    default:
                        return x;
                }
            }).SelectMany(x => x.Select((Value, Index) => new { Index, Value })).GroupBy(x => x.Index).Select(x => x.Select(y => y.Value));
```

Comment: You haven't shown the code that causes the `OutOfmemoryException`, it's not the `Enumerable.Repeat` because that is using deferred execution. Maybe you have used `ToList` or a `foreach` that fills a list. Of course you can't fill the memory infinitely. You have to process it in another way, for example by writing the result into a file or a database(f.e. by using [Batch processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing) or one "line" after the other).

Comment: he's getting `IEnumerable` the object does not exist until he call something like `.ToList()` so he has an object of Int,String(6 char),int,in,datetime(long i believe) and create 2.1 billions of these object. lets make a simple calculation of the bits footprint of that (32, 6x16,32,32,64) total 224 bits or 28 bytes. 2,147,483,647 times this is 55.9 gig of data.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have edited the post with the current implementation.

Comment: Out of memory exception occurs when I loop through this new collection. For each loop.

Comment: Yes, when iterating it will allocate the memory for the objects and check your ram. You probably run as 32bits the source code and you max allocation will be around 2 gig ram.

Comment: What platform target do you set for the project? Try x64 if you have a 64bit system to get the full power of your PC.

Comment: I cannot do batch processing because if I split the data then each batch will apply its own column logic.

Comment: At the moment for testing purposes, its a simple console application. Platform is AnyCPU

Comment: If you insist upon manipulating large data in tight loops, you might have to help things out a bit, and call `GC.Collect` yourself, perhaps during each loop iteration.  If that doesn't help, and you cannot control the resources used by your processing, then you'll have to redesign.

Comment: In case the data is retrieved from database, then this operation should happen in database. Otherwise, spawn multiple threads and do batch operations. For eg, a parallel foreach of 50 threads each having 1000 items each => at the end of one loop, it would have processed 50000 rows and ends up with 50 results. Once entire parallel foreach is executed you will have a collection of results, call this method recursively until you end up having single result. There might be more elegant way of doing it, just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, please.

This example when run on my machine consumes only a few megabytes of memory.

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>> data = Enumerable.Repeat(new List<object> { 10, "Twenty", 30, 40, DateTime.UtcNow }, int.MaxValue);

var hashSet = new HashSet<string>();

var result = data.Select((enumerable, index) =>
{
    var list = (List<object>)enumerable;

    if (index > 0) list[0] = null; // only 1 value

    // unique
    string str = (string)list[1];
    if (hashSet.Contains(str))
        list[1] = null;
    else
        hashSet.Add(str);

    list[2] = null; // disabled

    return list;
});

Console.WriteLine(result.Count());
```

The logic of "only 1 value" and "disabled" does not consumes memory at all.

To implement the logic of "unique" I used the `HashSet`. It consumes memory proportional to the number of unique elements. If the number of unique elements is little - everything will work fine. If the number of unique elements is many - there is nothing to do, the memory consumption will be great.